# jQuery event to trigger on form submit within the 'Billing' page

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying run an ajax request on the 'Billing' page - I would it to trigger the event once the 'billing' form has been submitted.

```
$(document).on('submit','form#co-billing-form',function(){
  // run some code
  alert('form submitted');
});
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to work - any ideas?

Comment: did you try listening to the click event of the button that submits the form instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice to use an observer for the event `checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method` as programming best practice to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: decided to use this route in the end